# Reading a cookie from different http requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am working with multiple websites that communicate with each other in a business. I am having some issues trying to ready a cookie set and read on the one domain, but requested from different domains. Excuse the explanation but here is my scenario: (.NET, MVC, c#)

First a link is requested: http://link1.com/action1. This link redirects to http://link2.com/action1 where a cookie is saved, and redirect the user away from this domain.

The User then proceed to http://link3.com/action1, and in this action I am using WebClient to call http://link2.com/action2 where I am trying to read the cookie that I stored in http://link2.com/action1 (NOTICE THAT THE DOMAIN THAT SETS THE COOKIE AND READS IT IS THE SAME, AND OF COURSE THE BROWSER ON THE CLIENT IS THE SAME)

The cookie is always null. I am guessing it is some cross-origin security issue and I can understand that. Or maybe the redirect has something to do with, I am not vary knowledgeable on cookies.

My question is, what is there an approach to get this working, given that the redirect functionality is important across all domains.

Thanks

Comment: Cookies are stored on the client, WebClient runs on the server. You need to pass this token in another way, through the request URL for example.

Comment: I do not know how I missed that. The amount of data to store is not suited for sessions.
I need a proper way to log a click on a page, and then when the user reaches another location, check that log if it exists. I cannot pass it in the parameter due to some limitations. @CodeCaster